# Why is this intersection method in the doubly circular linked list not working?

Tags: java, list

```
public static DCLL inter(DCLL a, DCLL b) {
        Element curA = a.head;
        DCLL c = new DCLL();
        
        if(a.head == null || b.head == null)
            return c;
        
        while(curA != a.rear) {
            if(b.isInList(curA.data)) {
                c.insert(curA.data);
                curA = curA.next;
                c.length++;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
```

This is the intersection method where I should return a list that contains all the same elements in list `a` and `b`, but the program is looping infinitely and the only `while` loop in this method can loop infinitely, so I'm not getting why it's not working.

The `isInList()` and `insert()` methods works perfectly fine.

I updated my code and I think it will work but now I'm getting another error in the toString method in the line `s = " | " + cur.data + " | ";`. It's a null pointer exception but why is it an error?

```
        String s = " ";
        if(this.isEmpty())
            return"Empty list";
        
        Element cur = this.head;
        s = " | " + cur.data + " | ";
        cur = cur.next;
        while(cur != this.head) {
            s+= cur.data + " | ";
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: `curA = curA.next;` should be unconditional.

Comment: @user207421 what does that mean. Sorry I'm a beginner, and everyone tells me to debug or whatever but I just don't know them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating your currA in case b.isInList(curA.data) is false. Therefore you again and again check whether "curA != a.rear" and this will not change.

Comment: I updated my post and I got an error in the toString method. Why is that?

Comment: @P-Em You got *what* error?